# Virtualhosts not working, defaulting to html folder

Tags: virtualhost, rhel

I can't get virtualhosts to work, the server environment is RHEL

whenever I navigate to test.com it defaults to the index.html page in /www/html/ instead of the virtual server document root /var/www/test.com/public_html

below is an excerpt from the httpd.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
IncludeOptional "/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/*.conf"
```

in /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/test.com.conf  :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.test.com
ServerAlias test.com www.test.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

When I run httpd -S

```
...
    port 80 namevhost www.test.com (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/test.com.conf:                                                1)
                 alias test.com
                 alias www.test.com
    port 80 namevhost default-http (/etc/httpd/conf.d/25-default-http.conf:                                                  6)
...
```

I'm pretty new at this, any help appreciated thanks. I've also modified the hosts file on the client to point test.com to the server

Answer (score 0):

When testing this on a browser it was defaulting to https which listens on port 443.  I changed the listening port from 80 to 443: VirtualHost *:443 and it resolved.  Alternatively I could also use http://www.test.com to view the page.